# My logger will not log one of my log levels.(dealing with logging)

Tags: logging, levels, info

My GitHub is WalthrustN. In a path = my_Python_project/Logging/HelperLog.py, I am trying to figure out why the code doesn't log info levels to the console. Its weird because it logs all other levels + when I import the file with another project. It manages to log the level then. I am confused. Please help. email = Wavyvillain@gmail.com

https://github.com/WalthrustN/my_Python_project/blob/n/Logging/HelperLog.py

`````````````python``````````````````````````````````

`enter code here`import logging

#create own internal logger (not the root logger)
`enter code here`logger = logging.getLogger(**name**)
`enter code here`logger.propagate = False

`enter code here`logger.info('hello from helper')

`# Propagate: Decides whether a log should be propagated` to the logger's parent

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Custom loggers can not be modified with `basicConfig()`.

You can either use the root logger, e.g using *logging*.warning().

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.warning('this is a warning')
logging.info('hello from helper')
```

or add a `StreamHandler`

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
h = logging.StreamHandler()
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(h)
logger.warning('this is a warning')
logger.info('hello from helper')
```